# invoke firebase api from chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firebase

I'm trying to call the [set](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html) method of the firebase api from a chrome extension.
Since I was having issues loading the firebase.js from the cdn I decided to download it and include it in my package.
But now I'm getting:

> Refused to load the script
>   'https://mydomain.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=323&cb=1&v=5'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".
>   Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is
>   used as a fallback. (anonymous function) @ firebase241.js:168
>   firebase241.js:168 Refused to load the script

When the firebase script executes.
I know it is something related to [permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) or [content_security_policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) from my extensionmanifest. But I've tried doing this:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://mydomain.firebaseio.com/; object-src 'self'",
```

and that:

```
  "permissions": [
    "gcm",
    "storage",
    "notifications",
    "https://*.firebase.com/",
    "https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js",
    "https://mydomain.firebaseio.com/*",
  ],
```

with no luck.

I'm also getting this:

> There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
>   'content_security_policy' is only allowed for extensions and legacy
>   packaged apps, but this is a packaged app.

when I set the content_security_policy in the manifest.js

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://mydomain.firebaseio.com/; object-src 'self'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'content_security_policy' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps, **but this is a packaged app**

What you have is not an extension, but an [app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps). Which is defined by having an `"app"` key in the manifest.

Apps [cannot override CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy).

You need to solve this identity crisis:

- If you really mean to have an extension, you need to remove `"app"` key and make a real extension.
- If you're confused about terminology and you really mean to write a Chrome App, the proper approach is [sandboxing](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#sandboxing).

Comment: after finding this I realized that I was making an app instead of an extension.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-chrome-extension

but still couldn't  understand why it wouldn't work in the same way. thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. there is an explicit solution in the [Firebase Blog](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-03-06-power-your-chrome-extension-with-firebase.html) you need to "content_security_policy" into this:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.firebase.com 
https://*.firebaseio.com; object-src 'self'"
```

it worked great for me!

Comment: that's what I did. when I added:
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://mydomain.firebaseio.com/; object-src 'self'"

and still had issues. the reason: because I was trying to do it in an app instead of an extension. as Xan mentioned.

Comment: that's exactly the problem:
**Don't use mydomain.firebaseio.com but *.firebaseio.com.
copy-paste the exact code i shared without changing anything.**
Firebase are saying that you shouldn't use yourdomain.firebaseio.com because their frameworks uses other subdomains as well

Comment: again...are you using it as an app?
I've used *.firebaseio.com at first and got the same issue.
and them changed it to an extension (in the manifest) and worked fine even with [not really my domain].firebaseio.com.

what does you manifest look like?

Comment: look at the only firebase example they've got...it's an extension instead of an app.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-chrome-extension/blob/master/manifest.json

Comment: i had the same error as you and when i copy-paste the line i shared, it's gone.
I created an extension, not an app. maybe we had the same error from different reasons.
just tried to help